# Revolution Slider in Vue Component

Tags: vue.js, jquery-plugins, revolution-slider

The 2 slides on the homepage and the Revolution PLugin only needs to run for that component. I am only sharing code for one slide to keep things simple.

To get things partially working I have loaded the revolution slider js files in the head of the index file.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
```

I then load the JS needed to load the sliders at the end of the index file just before the closing body tag. This slides only load if the homepage is the initially loaded route for Vue. If I navigate away from the home page and then back the slides do not load again.

```js
jQuery("#rev_slider_1_1").show().revolution({
 // slider options ...
});
</body>
```

I have tried to move this code into the home component within the mounted property.

```js
mounted () {
    this.$nextTick( function() {
        jQuery("#rev_slider_1_1").show().revolution({
            // slider options ...
        });
    });
}
```

When I do this I get revolution is not a function

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).show(...).revolution is not a function
```

In the end I need to be able to navigate to the homepage from within my Vue App and have the sliders load without a full page load.

Comment: Hi how you solved this issue

Comment: I didn't get it working. I only had single image slides using animation and parallax features. I ended up manually building out each slide to have a similar action.